# What is the psychological explanation for misrepresented common understanding?

Tags: communication

If a person (say your boss) thinks you are on the same page but you are not. Basically, they believe that you agree with them but you don't. There is a gap between their ability to recognize a dissonance between your view and theirs. I was so sure there was a term to describe this (having never studied psychology). Is there?

Could this be in the area of gaslighting?

Comment: [Gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) is very different to genuinely believing you are both on the same page. Can you please provide within your question why you think this could be Gaslighting?

Comment: This is likely to be some form of [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) - that is, they believe they are on the same page because it supports their pre-existing beliefs.

Comment: I'll have to agree with you there. Some form of confirmation bias.